# Dynamic cell height in slickgrid?

Tags: slickgrid

I have to display cell content like 
   Policy
   Part
   Cert
Separated with next line character 
In slickgrid table and so on.
How can I do this?
I searched but nothing worked for me.
What should I do with this is there any way to fit contents by height.

I Have this code written for breaking cells

```
columnname: <p>+policy+</p><br/>+part......and so on.
```

Any lead will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better register a new formatter for your column.

**Example**

```
 function myformatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
       return "<style='text-decoration: underline;color: #669900;height:120px;'>" + value +";
    }
```

And call myformatter into column definition

```
var columns = [];
    columns[0] = { id: "id", name: "columnname", field: "id", sortable: true, width: 5, formatter: myformatter };
```

Comment: Welcome and i hope the above code is working for your cell style.